# интернет-магазин на PHP. В корзину добавляется только один товар

Tags: php

Делаю интернет магазин на ПХП. При клике на кнопку "добавить товар в корзину" - отправляю Get-запросом id товара. Проблема в том, что в корзину добавляется не больше одного товара (того, на котором кликнули), кликаешь на другой товар - добавляется он, а предыдущий - исчезает. нужна помощь знатоков в доведении кода до ума) чтобы товары нормально добавлялись. Ниже - код добавления в корзину.

```
if(isset($_GET['add'])){    
    $_SESSION['id'] = $_GET['add'];
    require_once 'connection.php';

    $link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database) or die("Error!" . mysqli_error($link));
    $link->set_charset("utf8");
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM books WHERE id="' .$_SESSION['id']. '"';
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die("Error!" . mysqli_error($link));
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result); 
    echo "<p>" .$row['author']. ' ' .$row['name']. ' ' .$row['price']." руб.</p>";  
} else {
    echo "<p>В корзине - пусто</p>";
}
```

Comment: а что вы хотите добавить, помимо кликнутого товара? оО

Comment: Я вообще в этом коде не увидел добавления в корзину, вывод вижу.

Comment: наверное 2 единицы товара разом добавить, тогда второе поле используйте `if(isset($_GET['num_goods'] > 1)){ //добавить х-товаров`

Comment: Это не код добавления в корзину а код вывода выбранного товара по данным из сессии. Вы туда в одном то же место пишите ID товара, любого, на который нажал пользователь.